Why does a graph of radius vs velocity of an object undergoing circular motion have a quadratic slope?
I'm doing a project with uniform circular motion and I cannot for the life of me understand the conceptual side of the graphs. On a graph of velocity vs radius of a bob undergoing uniform circular motion, there is a quadratic increase. I already understand the equation, but I don't know why it would be that way from a conceptual standpoint.
The same goes for a graph of velocity vs the force of tension.
Is the radius one because the area of a circle is r^2? If anyone can give any insight that would be wonderful.



Do you have the graph to show, by any chance? For uniform circular motion, the radius would be constant, so I do not fully understand what graph you are refering to. And are you by velocity refering to the speed, perhaps? When you mention the force of tension, then it sounds like you have a specific scenario in mind, because there does not have to be a tension force involved in circular motion. If you could clarify and show some graphs or equations, then that would make your question much clearer.

added the graphs!

The centripetal force required to keep an object of mass $m$ moving at a speed $v$ in a circle of radius $r$ is $mv^2/r$, which is quadratic in $r$.

@b_cipher the addition as links didn't work. You can embed (via drag and drop) png/jpeg etc with the site's interface. Very easy, even for me.

The line plotted on the radius vs velocity graph isn't quadratic. Please revise your question. Can you also put error bars on the points, otherwise one cannot say what relationships there may or may not be between the variables. There would appear to be more than 2 variables in your experiment. How are the others kept constant?

A graph of velocity vs radius can have any curve you like depending on depending on the constraints of the system. Your question is very unclear. You need to specify what the system and constraints are for anyone to be able to help you.

Are you aware the radius of a circle is not $r^2$? Please clean up your question and provide the additional details requested.

@b_cipher There are already 2 out of the required 3 votes to close the question, presumably due to lack of clarity. If you don't want you question to be closed, you should edit and clarify your question.


The same goes for a graph of velocity vs the force of tension

For a bob of mass m on the end of a string moving in a circle of radius r, the centripetal force that keeps the bob moving in a circle is provided by the tension in the string. Centripetal force F is is given by $F = M \omega^2 r = M v^2 / r$. This means the relationship between tension and velocity is $F \propto v^2$ and the relationship is indeed quadratic.

On a graph of velocity vs radius of a bob undergoing uniform circular
motion, there is a quadratic increase.

You have not specified the scenario precisely. I am going to assume the bob is with moving with constant angular momentum and the radius is altered. If we treat the bob as an idealised point particle, the angular momentum L is given by $L = I \omega = m r^2 \omega = m r v$  In this context $v \propto r$ and the graph is linear, not quadratic.
If we assume the string is elastic and the radius increases due to stretching as the tangential velocity increases, then the relationship between the radius and the velocity can be found using Hooke's law ($F = k\Delta X =$), where $\Delta X $ is the extension of the string and k is the stiffness constant of the string. In this case $$R = X + \Delta X = X+ kF = X + kM v^2 / R,$$  where X is the relaxed length of the string. Solving for R gives us $$R =  v \sqrt{kM +X^2}+ X/2.$$  This implies that the relationship between radius and velocity is still linear even in the elastic scenario.

Is the radius one because the area of a circle is r^2?

The area of a circle is actually $A = \pi r^2$. If $A = r^2$ this implies $\pi r^2 = r^2$ and $\pi =1$ which is obviously not correct.

Is the radius one because the area of a circle is r^2?

The area of a circle is actually $A = \pi r^2$. If $A = r^2$ this implies $\pi r^2 = r^2$ and $\pi =1$ which is obviously not correct. Even if we use the correct definition for the area of a circle the radius cannot be determined, without additional information.
Above both your graphs are some equations in x and r but you have not told us what the variables are or where the equations come from. If you clearly define all the parameters and equations in your scenario, this will help you find the clarity required to find the solution you are looking for.
